# why do we need For loop to manipulate document.querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");  
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
    lis[i].addEventListener("click", function());
```

Why can't we do this instead?

```
lis.addEventListener("click", function());
```

Comment: Because array does not have `.addEventListener`, it's not jQuery

Comment: You *can* do something similar if the selected items are all children of some container - use event delegation

Comment: Delegation as in `document.querySelector("ul").addEventListener("click",function(e) { if (e.target.tagName=="LI") console.log(this.innerText)});`